Python: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing lib: The specified procedure could not be found
python programming newbie here. I was trying to create a simple histogram with altair using the following code. The dataset is large, around 1,000 rows.
count_chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('r:Q', bin=True),
    y=alt.Y('count():Q')
).properties(title='Histogram plot of r counts')
count_chart

But received the following error message:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
`ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py:977, in MimeBundleFormatter.__call__(self, obj, include, exclude)
    974     method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    976     if method is not None:
--> 977         return method(include=include, exclude=exclude)
    978     return None
    979 else:

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\altair\vegalite\v5\api.py:2576, in TopLevelMixin._repr_mimebundle_(self, include, exclude)
   2574     return {}
   2575 else:
-> 2576     return renderers.get()(dct)

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\altair\utils\display.py:227, in HTMLRenderer.__call__(self, spec, **metadata)
    224 kwargs.update(metadata)
    225 # To get proper return value type, would need to write complex
    226 # overload signatures for spec_to_mimebundle based on `format`
--> 227 return spec_to_mimebundle(  # type: ignore[return-value]
    228     spec, format="html", output_div=self.output_div, **kwargs
    229 )

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\altair\utils\mimebundle.py:70, in spec_to_mimebundle(spec, format, mode, vega_version, vegaembed_version, vegalite_version, embed_options, engine, **kwargs)
     68 internal_mode: Literal["vega-lite", "vega"] = mode
     69 if using_vegafusion():
---> 70     spec = compile_with_vegafusion(spec)
     71     internal_mode = "vega"
     73 # Default to the embed options set by alt.renderers.set_embed_options

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\altair\utils\_vegafusion_data.py:226, in compile_with_vegafusion(vegalite_spec)
    224 # Pre-evaluate transforms in vega spec with vegafusion
    225 row_limit = data_transformers.options.get("max_rows", None)
--> 226 transformed_vega_spec, warnings = vf.runtime.pre_transform_spec(
    227     vega_spec,
    228     vf.get_local_tz(),
    229     inline_datasets=inline_tables,
    230     row_limit=row_limit,
    231 )
    233 # Check from row limit warning and convert to MaxRowsError
    234 handle_row_limit_exceeded(row_limit, warnings)

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\vegafusion\runtime.py:364, in VegaFusionRuntime.pre_transform_spec(self, spec, local_tz, default_input_tz, row_limit, preserve_interactivity, inline_datasets, keep_signals, keep_datasets, data_encoding_threshold, data_encoding_format)
    362 else:
    363     local_tz = local_tz or get_local_tz()
--> 364     imported_inline_dataset = self._import_or_register_inline_datasets(inline_datasets)
    366     # Parse input keep signals and datasets
    367     keep_signals = parse_variables(keep_signals)

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\vegafusion\runtime.py:217, in VegaFusionRuntime._import_or_register_inline_datasets(self, inline_datasets)
    214         except ValueError:
    215             pass
--> 217     imported_inline_datasets[name] = PandasDatasource(value)
    218 elif hasattr(value, "__dataframe__"):
    219     # Let polars convert to pyarrow since it has broader support than the raw dataframe interchange
    220     # protocol, and "This operation is mostly zero copy."
    221     try:

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\vegafusion\datasource\pandas_datasource.py:13, in PandasDatasource.__init__(self, df, sample_size, batch_size)
     11 def __init__(self, df: "pd.DataFrame", sample_size: int = 1000, batch_size: int = 8096):
     12     import pandas as pd
---> 13     import pyarrow as pa
     15     fields = []
     16     casts = {}

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyarrow\__init__.py:65
     63 _gc_enabled = _gc.isenabled()
     64 _gc.disable()
---> 65 import pyarrow.lib as _lib
     66 if _gc_enabled:
     67     _gc.enable()

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing lib: The specified procedure could not be found.`

Before getting this error message, I got an error message about the size of the dataset, so I used this line of code before the code for the histogram: alt.data_transformers.enable("vegafusion"), as this is supposed to be helpful for large datasets. But I then received the error message above.
I also tested a smaller dataset with the same code for the histogram, and it worked.
Thanks for any suggestions you can provide.

There is something going wrong while importing the pyarrow dependency. Just import pyarrow will probably give the same error

1,000 rows is very small dataset. If you would have few millions or few GB then it would be large.

error try to load some C/C++ library and it may need to check pyarrow depenencies on its home page - it may need to install some C/C++ library which is not a python code.

Installing PyArrow — Apache Arrow v16.1.0
